# Cannot solve issue of memory management in operating system

Tags: memory-management, operating-system, paging

I had operating exam a week a go and I faced the following question:
[image]

I solved the first part in this way :

2^32/2^12=2^20 * 4 =4* 2^20   size of page table

First I want to see if my answer is right? then for the second part I have no Idea how to solve it I read chapter 8 of operating system concept but could not get any idea how to solve it...

Can anyone help?

Comment: I feel if I divide 2^20 resulted from part 1 by 2^12 i get the answer I mean 2^20/2^12=2^8 am I right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question talks about two cases:

1st Case: When single level paging is enabled (1st Question)
2nd Case: When two level paging is enabled (2nd question)

(Refer [this link](http://cs.uttyler.edu/Faculty/Rainwater/COSC3355/Animations/twolevelpaging.htm) to see how two-level paging is perceived graphically )

Now, to get the size of page-table we need **Number of Page-Table Entries** and **Size of each entry** and we multiply it to get size of page table.

Given, Size of page-table entry - 4 Bytes

For **Question 1:**

Given, Size of virtual memory: 2^32 bytes
Size of each page: 2^12 bytes
So, Max number of pages that virtual mermory can allocate: 2^(32-12) - **2^20 pages**
This means, in a case of single level paging page table will consists of 2^20 page table entries.

Currently, we have number of page table entries and size of each page table entry which consitute size of single level page-table i.e

```
**2^20(page-table entries) * 4 ( size of each page-table entry in bytes)**
```

**2nd Question:**

The statement says that page-size used for paging the page-table is 2^12 bytes which means single-level page-table is further divided into blocks of 2^12 bytes each which means after dividing the page-table into 2^12 bytes blocks we, get

```
( 2^20 * 4 ( size of page table ) ) / ( 2 ^ 12 ( block size) ) = 2 ^ 10 page-tables
```

2^10 page tables can be formed at maximum.

To, find the size of 2nd level page table we need numer of entries and size of each page-table entry.

Number of entries are 2 ^ 10 as found above.
Size of each page table entry will be 10 bits which has to be converted into bytes, so we have to make it 16 bits to make it two bytes and size of second page - table will be

```
2 ^ 10 * 2
```

This is the answer to the second question